# Any way to transfer a UV map to a texture or SVG?

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, texture-coordinates

Maybe I'm just using the wrong search terms...

I want to paint some textures using an external program (shocking, right?). To do so, however, I need to know *where* to paint.

Is there any way to either stroke *an SDS*<sup>1,2</sup> UV wireframe onto a texture, or, better, export the UV wireframe as an SVG? (Ideal would be if only selected geometry is exported, since in my use case I only need to paint on specific parts of my object. But there are relatively easy ways to figure that out from the entire wireframe, so it's not a huge issue if I can only export everything...)

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> "Export UV" doesn't preserve SDS<sup>2</sup> outlines. It's not entirely clear if this matters, but I suspect it does?</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> Subdivision Surface.</sub>

Comment: In the UV editor go to the UV > Export UV Layout menu item. If the side panel in the file selector isn't visible, click 'N' to show it and you can then select SVG under Format to save in SVG format.

Comment: @JohnEason you're absolutely right. You should provide this solution as an answer to the question.

Comment: The above link to an earlier answer is somewhat out of date now because it's for a much earlier version of Blender! The question was closed before I could format an answer properly.

Comment: Yike! That extracts *as an image*? I'd assumed it dumped the actual *coordinates* to e.g. a text file .

Comment: @JohnEason, that doesn't preserve SDS outlines, though. Are those representative of the actual UV used by an SDS, or are the "lies"?

Comment: No It's purely an image of the UV layout as shown in the UV editor window. As far as I know there's no way of dumping the coordinates unless you start writing a Python script to do it. I've no idea what you mean by 'SDS'.

Comment: @JohnEason, SubDivision Surface? And the problem is it *isn't* "as shown in the UV editor window"; the editor takes the SDS modifier into account, but Export UV doesn't.

Comment: Ah! I see. I very rarely use the UV editor so didn't realise that.

Comment: @Matthew How could be Subdivision modifier taken into account in the UV Editor? Can you share your screen? I can't even imagine how it could be visually/geometrically done. https://imgur.com/zGRXLTP ... Thank you

Comment: @vklidu, I could've sworn I saw a difference in island edges, but apparently not. It definitely makes a difference *inside*, however. Just compare Sue (default UV will suffice) with and without SDS applied.